# keydown event with keys.Enter and keys.Tag

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

I'm using some richTextBoxes in one page of my form, in keyDown of richTextBoxes, i wrote if Ctrl+Enter is pressed, sendKeys the Tab key so the next one get focus, and I also have a keyDown event on whole form, so when user press Ctrl+Tab, selected page change to next page
problem is, when i press Ctrl+Enter on the richTextBoxes, keyDown of form with Ctrl+Tab happens and tab changes, why it sees enter and tab alike ?
Sorry for my bad grammar, and thanks for your effort
keyDown event of Main Form:

```
private void Main_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Control)
    {
        //code for changing the tabs
    }
}
```

keyDown event of richTextBoxes:

```
private void txtControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when you press a key, the focused control receives the key pressed. You could change a bit of this flow setting the `Form.KeyPreview` property to True. With this setting the Form receives the key pressed before the focused control.

You are messing with this *'normal'* flow trying to insert a fake TAB key while you are processing the KeyDown event that has reached the RichTextBox keydown event handler. You suppress the CTRL+ENTER key but, at the exit of the event, the TAB key is received by the form with the Control bit still set and, as far as I know, there is no easy way to reset this bit, hence you process a CTRL+TAB in your form keydown.

Fortunately all of this is not needed, you set the next control in tab order line simply with

```
private void txtControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Control current = sender as Control;
        this.SelectNextControl(current, true, true, true, true);
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

The call to the form method [SelectNextControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you a lot more control on what should happen and doesn't insert a fake TAB key in the keyboard processing.

Answer (score 0):

You send tab `SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");` on keydown. The modifier is stil CTRL. Than the keydown of the MainForm in focus catches Tab. Stop sending `SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");`?